# What's the historical interaction between the Wish spell and increasing ability scores?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming, wish

I vaguely recall *Wish*es in 1e affecting ability score increases going something like this:

- a single *Wish* spell could increase any ability score to 16
- you needed another *Wish* spell to get to 18
- then it was one *Wish* spell per point over that (with like 5 *Wish*es needed to get to 18/00 STR)

But now, looking through the 1e DMG, I can't find any of this. Ideally, I'd like information on how a *Wish* spell  would interact with ability score increases for each edition of D&D.

**What's the historical interaction between the *Wish* spell and increasing ability scores?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AD&D1e has rules for this, on p. 11 of the ***DMG***. A wish per point of ability, up to 16, then a wish per tenth of a point.

BECMI D&D has rules for Clerical wishes on p. 40 of the ***Rules Cyclopedia*** and for Magic-User wishes on p. 61. Raising an ability by one level requires as many wishes as the number of the new level, all of which must be cast within a week.

Comment: I don't see anything in the 1e DMG about 'a wish per point' up to 16.  Only about how *Wish*es affect ability scores at 16 and above. Can you quote where you got that part from?

Comment: @aaron9eee: So it doesn't. I was answering mainly from memory of forty years ago; I think we must have deduced a wish per point, the text is clear that you get more than a tenth of a point below 16. Several groups I played in had reached the same conclusion.

Comment: LOL, that 40 years truly does play havoc with memory!!

Answer (score 2):

3/3.5e are the only editions to explicitly allow an increase in ability scores using Wish.

- OD&D - no Wish
- [Greyhawk supplement 1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/33364/59609) - Wish is introduced, but no explicit effects, it's basically up to the DM
- 2e - Wish has no explicit effects again
- [3e](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/wish.htm) -  "Grant a creature a +1 inherent bonus to an ability score. Two to five wish spells cast in immediate succession can grant a creature a +2 to +5 inherent bonus to an ability score (two wishes for a +2 inherent bonus, three for a +3 inherent bonus, and so on). Inherent bonuses are instantaneous, so they cannot be dispelled. Note: An inherent bonus may not exceed +5 for a single ability score, and inherent bonuses to a particular ability score do not stack, so only the best one applies."
- 4e - wish isn't in this edition
- [5e](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) - no interaction

Comment: May wanna check BECMI

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil It's in there, but I don't have any of the source books or know a good site to confirm the rules.